# paradoxical manipulation based on law of total probability

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, expected-value

I am trying to resolve the following paradoxical result when I am using law of total probability to manipulate some expression, but can't seem to be able to.

Suppose we have random variable $X, Y, Z$, with joint distribution $p(x, y, z)$, and we want to calculate $\mathbb E_{p(x,y)}[f(x,y)]$ for some sufficiently nice-behaving function $f$ (i.e. the expectation is taken over the marginal over $X, Y$.

So we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb E_{p(x,y)}[f(x,y)]&=\int_{x, y}p(x, y)f(x, y) dxdy\\
&=\int_{x,y} p(x)p(y|x)f(x, y) dxdy\\
&=\int_{x} p(x) \int_y p(y|x)f(x, y) dy dx\\
&=\int_x p(x) g(x) dx\\
&=\int_{x,z}p(x,z) g(x) dzdx\\
&=\int_z p(z)\int_x p(x|z) g(x) dx dz\\
&=\int_z p(z)\int_x p(x|z) \int_y p(y|x)f(x, y) dx dy dz\\
&=\int_z p(z)\int_x \int_y p(x|z) p(y|x)f(x, y) dy dx dz\\
&=\int_{x,y,z} p(z) p(x|z) p(y|x) f(x, y) dxdydz, 
\end{align}
where $g(x)=\int_y p(y|x)f(x, y) dy$ is a function of $x$.

However, another way of derivation is as follows:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E_{p(x,y)}[f(x,y)]&=\int_{x, y}p(x, y)f(x, y) dxdy\\
&=\int_{x,y,z}p(x,y,z)f(x,y)dxdydz\\
&=\int_{x,y,z}p(z)p(x|z)p(y|x,z)f(x,y)dxdydz\\
\end{align}

So the above two derivations seem to suggest that $p(y|x)=p(y|x,z)$, but this is obviously not true for general joint distributions. So what one is correct? Or maybe both are correct (or wrong)?

Comment: You have left $z$ out of the initial part of the derivations, then introduced it partway through in both cases.  Naturally this is likely to cause you difficulties.  From your expectation operator's subscript, it does not appear that $z$ is relevant at all.

Comment: @jbowman the expectation is defined on $f(x,y)$ with respected to the marginal over $x, y$, so $z$ doesn't show up for in the expectation. But I don't think it would be wrong to introduce $z$ partway in the derivation? $z$ is indeed not relevant to the expectation, but I am confused why two derivations lead to $p(y|x)=p(y|x,z)$.

Comment: Look at the third from bottom line of your first derivation; you have $p(y|x)$.  You have left off the "$z$", although you did include it in the second derivation.   You have also left $dy$ off of this line (clearly an oversight.)

Comment: @jbowman I fixed the day omission, but I don't think I missed the $z$ in $p(y|x)$, because that part is from substituting $g(x)$ back.